# Delayed Jobs isn't logging on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I managed to log into a custom log file using this configuration:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = 
  ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new("log/#{Rails.env}_delayed_jobs.log", Rails.logger.level)
```

It's working locally. I can see the file change and all the logs I want.

But the problem is that when I deploy to Heroku and run the job, and try to read the contents of the file through the console, I don't get the expected results.

```
irb(main):070:0* File.read('/app/log/production_delayed_jobs.log')
=> "# Logfile created on 2013-06-20 08:36:43 +0000 by logger.rb/25413\n"
```

Note that I set the loggin level to :debug in production. In config/environments/production.rb I have this configuration:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

Comment: I don't think you can save local files on heroku because of their dyno architecture. Each server has its own app/log directory. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: And you shouldn't use file based logging on heroku. If you need more than `heroku logs` take a look at logging addons https://addons.heroku.com/#logging (personally I use Papertrail)

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'll look at these articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically @yoav is right, you can't write to your own log files on heroku (no file system access). what you can do is described in the heroku logs right here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log